# ORA-06413 error when try to open connection in a MVC 4 application

Tags: c#, oracle, asp.net-mvc-4, iis-express

I have an DLL which is responsible to make the queries on the database. In that DLL I have a method that opens the connection between the application and the database, as seen below:

```
private OracleConnection _InitConnection()
{
    this.LastException = null;
    this.Errors        = new List<Exception>();

    OracleConnection conn = null;

    try
    {
        conn = new OracleConnection("Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=***)(PORT=***)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=****)(SERVER = DEDICATED))); User Id=***; Password=***;");

        conn.Open();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        this.LastException= ex;
        this.Errors.Add(ex);
    }

    return conn;
}
```

I use the `System.Data.OracleClient.dll`,  version 2.0.50727, to manage the connection.

This DLL is used by an MVC 4 Web Application, implemented using C# and .Net Framework 4.0.

When I use this DLL in a Windows Forms project I can connect to the database without any trouble. However, when I try to use the same DLL in a MVC system or using WebForms, I get an error.

The error that I get is the `ORA-06413 - Connection not Open`.This happen when I run the application in an ISS Express, set to run as 32 bits.

When I change the ISS Express to 64 bits I get the error `OCIEnvCreate failed with return code -1 but error message text was not available`.

Comment: Most solutions I have seen for this is due to the location of your application. It seems it doesn't like weird characters etc in the path. Try moving the solution to a short path with alpha numeric only naming.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I've found the problem.

In the project I was using some libraries from another project. One of those was configured as follows in the .csproj file

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
 <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
 <DebugType>full</DebugType>
 <Optimize>false</Optimize>
 <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
 <DefineConstants>TRACE;DEBUG</DefineConstants>
 <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
 <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
 <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
</PropertyGroup>
```

That means that the compiled version of this program woul'd be stored in the \bin\Debug path.
However, the console application that I've using to test the library has the following configuration:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
 <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
 <Optimize>true</Optimize>
 <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
 <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
 <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
 <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
 <Prefer32Bit>false</Prefer32Bit>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Wich means that the output of the program would be stored at bin\Release.
That caused the problem, because when my console application tried to use the library, it was in another folder.
It wasn't possible to solve that inside the VS2015, but the problem disapeared when I changed the property group of my console application to the same configuration as my library was.